# How do I simply close a few widget windows?

Tags: interface

[image]

I am losing my mind trying to figure out how simply close widget that was so easy to open to begin with.

[x] close button doesn’t seem to exist in this program so what’s a guy gotta do to close a window in blender 2.8? I also can’t close the widget with “transform | View | 3d cursor | annotations” window either.  I’m extremely frustrated and I’d really appreciate the help

Comment: Hit the 'T' button on your keyboard. Please watch any of the numerous Blender 2.80 UI videos on youtube.

Comment: Thank you very much, and honest to god I’ve watched three tuts and not one has mentioned it.Albeit I’m not the best listener either. thanks again

Comment: The Blender UI has always been a little confusing at first and you have to get used to it. But after a while everything makes a lot of sense, because it's faster to work with.

Comment: You can also slide the right border of the window, to the left (=resize the window to 0).

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open/close the Toolbar on the left, and <kbd>N</kbd> to open/close the Sidebar on the right.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/keymap/blender_default.html#common-editor-keys